# How do I apply Superpowered effect on other apps installed?

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, superpowered

I want to deploy Superpowered SDK into my project but I need clarity on how to use the APIs before proceeding. Also I need to know, more importantly, if superpowered is the solution I need right now.

My task on android is this;
I want to use the `SuperpoweredFilter` effects class on the audioprocessing of other apps installed on device. If I was using the default APIs in android, I would simply achieve this by setting the AudioSessionId parameter to 0, instead of passing the android `MediaPlayer()` AudioSessionId into  the instance of the effects class.

Example in android;

```
BassBoost fx = new BassBoost (int priority, int audioSessionId);
```

//setting the audioSessionId to 0 instead of `myMediaPlayer.getAudioSessionId` makes this sound effect apply to other installed apps on device outside the context of myMediaPlayer variable.

How is it possible to use the SuperpoweredFilter and audioprocessing's short float output to send this same effect over to other apps installed on my device? Is this even possible?